# Gatsby can't query frontmatter

Tags: javascript, markdown, gatsby

I am learning Gatsby.js right now and I ran into a problem. I have installed transformer plugin and I have a .md file in which I have title,stack and slug.

```
title :Place Sharing Website
stack :React.js & Node.js
slug :place-sharing
---

### You can share the places that you visited
```

I want to query that title,stack and slug. But I can't do that. Here is the code I tried to do that.

```
allMarkdownRemark {
  nodes {
    frontmatter {
      title
      stack
      slug
    }
  }
}
}
```

it didn't work.

Here is my gatsby.config file

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-transformer-remark",
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `notes`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/notes/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `projects`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/projects/`,
      },
    },
  ],
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "My Homepage",
    description: "This is where I write my thoughts.",
  },
}
```

Here is how I am trying to query it.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There should be `---` at the top of the markdown file. Also try going to `localhost:PORT/__graphql` to see if the markdown file is detected

Comment: There is --- at the top of the markdown file in my code editor I forgot to add it in the question. No, it is not detected in localhost:8000__graphql.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have formatting issues. Try:

```
title: Place Sharing Website
stack: React.js & Node.js
slug: place-sharing
```

And check the creation of the markdown file, the fields should be wrapped inside `---`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used space and it did work.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue. Happy coding! :)